# How to parse an png image to an gzip encoded API - Powershell

Tags: image, powershell

How can I get an png image that is like in my "C:" and upload it into an API that is using Accept-encoding: gzip, deplate, br?

I have the API call built but I just don't know how to parse an image to a variable in powershell to put it in the body

Glad

Comment: Have a look at .NET API classes `GZipStream` and `DeflateStream`.

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest`/`Invoke-RestMethod` will automatically take care of stream encoding (including compression), you don't need to do anything special. Does the API documentation say anything specific about the format of the uploaded file? Does it accept regular form uploads, or does it say you need to manually base64-encode the content (or similar)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen
Unfortunately, there is no doc for this API so far. I was able to use this API on postman by using multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary1BI5fzCDiXQxHzt5 and using the file select option on postman. But unfortunately, idk how postman handles it. When I see in a http sniffer, what i can see is:

------WebKitFormBoundary1BI5fzCDiXQxHzt5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Icon"; filename="180.png"
Content-Type: image/png

 PNG

   
(lot of more strings and symbols)
------WebKitFormBoundary1BI5fzCDiXQxHzt5--

Comment: In that case `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://host.fqdn/api/endpoint" -Method Post -InFile path\to\file.png` should do :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen When using infile I can't add more things to the body to complete the WebKitFormBoundary. Do I need the WebKitFormBoundary now, or should I change the "Content-type"?

Comment: The cmdlet will take care of constructing the request, including the content boundaries, you don't need to do anything

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen
Thanks for your guidance. Seems to be not working at all. I'll just need to wait for the documentation to see how the body should be formatted in order to update a icon to this API. Thanks

Comment: If you need to do the compression and expansion manually this little module might help you get started https://github.com/santysq/PS-GZip